# Integrate a Bigquery procedure into DBT

Tags: google-bigquery, user-defined-functions, dbt, bigquery-udf

I am working on building a pipeline in DBT.
I have a stored procedure in Bigquery that I used to run in big query in an exploratory way.

The procedure is called using in BQ:
`CALL project_id.my_procedure(table_name , column_name)`
The procedure runs two dynamic queries (based on table and column names given in input).

- The first query will perform a search operation and returns a temporary table,
- The second query  inserts into a log table some information about the execution
- the third step is just:

> SELECT * FROM the table created in step1.

[image]
I would like to run this procedure in DBT by giving it a name of a view/ table in DBT and use the output (the temporary table) in the flow.

Is this possible, I read about using Macros  but I didn't figure out how to capture the output.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Does this [link](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/quickstarts/dbt-cloud/bigquery) help you in resolving the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could use dbt vars (https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/var#variable-default-values) in the models you want to create.

So `model_a` will perform a search operation and output a table and run the insert to log table with a dbt post-hook (https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/pre-hook-post-hook).

Then you can run `model_b` which will have a reference to `model_a` that will execute afterwards. So the dbt command will look something like:

`dbt run model_a model_b --vars='{table_name: table_a, column_name: column_a}'`

Answer (score 0):

We choose to code the content of the procedure in DBT. I used a macro that other analysts could call in their pipelines.

I think it is the best option as we still have the lineage.